# java rest web service by post method

Tags: java, web, service

I am trying to do a java rest web service using "POST" method.But i am unable to access the passed parameter.                                                         Here is my client part to invoke the web service.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Client client = Client.create();

            WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/wsRevDash/rest/post/testing");


            Form form=new Form();

            form.add("sc","pqr");



            ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
               .post(ClientResponse.class,form);

            if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                     + response.getStatus());
            }

            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println(output);

          } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          }

        }
```

And here is my java rest web service.

```
    @POST
    @Path("testing")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String createDataInJSON(@FormParam("sc") String data) { 

        System.out.println("Hello"+data);
        JSONObject jObjDevice = new JSONObject();


        jObjDevice.put("Hello",data); 
        return jObjDevice.toJSONString();

    }
```

When i run on SoapUI,I am getting {"Hello":null}.
Please suggest me some way to cope with this.

Comment: SoapUI ... rest . why that mix? there are far better tools to test rest.
step 1: run your rest service (on debug) and try to contact it using a rest client. if that works, continue to the next steps

Comment: The web service works fine without passing parameters,but facing difficulty while accessing parameters.

Comment: might be the type of parameter. have you tried PathParam or RequestParam?

Comment: Ya,but getting same thing.And in the client part I have used form,so how can i use other annotations such as PathParam or RequestParam.

Comment: forget the client for now. first make sure your service works.

Comment: The service works fine.But passing the parameters can be done from client side only.And the main difficulty i am facing is accessing the passed parameters.

Comment: I've just noticed you've asked the same question 6 times :-|

Comment: @PriteshNaik did my answer work for you?

Comment: Hello @pruntlar,thank you for going through my code and giving me the response.But if the input contains two or many parameters,then how you will access the specific parameter?What you have suggested is to access the whole input.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `form` to a `String`:

```
String input = new Gson().toJson(form);
```

And pass in `input` to the response:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
               .post(ClientResponse.class,input);
```

And amend your web service to something like:

```
 @POST 
 @Path("/post") 
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
     public Response createDataInJSON(String data) { 
     String result = "Hello: " + data; 
     return Response.status(200).entity(result).build(); 
 }
```

And you need to remove 'testing' from your initial path:

```
 WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/wsRevDash/rest/post/testing"); <---- here
```

And include a slash before it in the web service:

```
@Path("/testing")
```

Comment: I'm assuming your path isn't meant to be 'testing/testing'.